# 2020 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

The 2020 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://dba.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: What  is the voting system used? Is it simple FPTP (First Past The Post) or is a more [sophisticated mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_transferable_vote) the chosen method?

Comment: @Vérace SE always uses [Meek STV](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77541/269301).

Comment: @Mast - thanks for that - it's great to see that it's STV PR - albeit slightly different from my own country (Ireland) where we don't do the fractional transfers - less important for elections where there are millions of eligible voters as opposed to StackExchange! Interestingly, in the 6 counties of the North, they use fractional voting - possibly because electoral tensions are a bit more (ahem...) fraught there! :-)

Comment: @Vérace In some SE elections, less than 50 users vote. There's a bit of a difference indeed.